# Is it possible to move the /home directory without reinstalling the whole computer?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, home-directory

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a 50 GB SSD partition (+9.9 GB swap). I also have a mechanical drive with >= 105GB free Ext4 partition in that computer. I'm running out of space on that SSD partition. I'd like to move the entire /home folder to that mech drive. How would I do that?

Comment: The 'standard' way would be to use a separate home partition and specify a separate line in `/etc/fstab` for that purpose: `/home` corresponding to `/` in the line for the root partition in field #2 according to `man fstab`.

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) for more details how to use several partitions for the system directories.

Comment: @sudodus: I assume the use of the Live system. How to correctly copy the contents of the old /home folder to the new partition while preserving the appropriate attributes?

Comment: @TomášPečený, Yes, it is a good idea to use a live system. I would copy with rsync: `sudo rsync -Havn source/ target/`; The trailing slash after the source directory is important. See `man rsync` for more details. Remove the option `n` when you see that the 'dry run' looks good to do the real thing: `sudo rsync -Hav source/ target/`

Comment: I do not think you are running out of memory you are running out of hard disk space.

Comment: @sudodus: I don't understand the -Havn or -Hav parameters, I don't see them in the manual.

Comment: @sudodus: Please excuse me, I can already see how the parameters are composed

Comment: H - copy hard links as hard links, a - archive (keep time, ownership and permissions), v - verbose (print which files are copied, in dry run, which files to be copied), n - dry run.

Comment: The procedure is here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving No live USB necessary. I have executed this procedure successfully.